# Cannot build cordova android APP (gradle error)

Tags: android, macos, cordova, build.gradle, cordova-5.0.0

I have several problems to build an android APP with cordova.

I do following steps:

```
cordova create example com.example.app example
cd example
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova build.
```

In this last step (cordova build) I get the following error:

[image]

My $ANDROID_HOME variable is correct.

My $JAVA_HOME variable is correct too.

I tried to change android:targetSdkVersion to 21 in my AndrodManifest.xml file with no luck.

I tried also:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

I have installed and updated last versions of Android SDK (API 22, API 21 and API 19).

Some info:

> Cordova version: 5.0.0
>
> OS: MAC OSX Yosemite
>
> Node version: 0.12.2

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Android platform version: 4.0.0

Comment: Do you have Android SDK Build-tools version 19 or above installed. Today I ran into same issue.